# How do I convert this function with an InvokeOperation callback to Reactive Extensions?

Tags: system.reactive

I have a RIA Services data service that has several function calls that look like this:

```
public InvokeOperation<T> SomeFunc(
    SomeData data,
    Action<InvokeOperation<T>> callback,
    object userState)
```

How would I use this with Reactive Extensions so I can subscribe to the callback and get the InvokeOperation result?

---

**Update**: here is my current implementation of Enigmativity's hybrid solution.    I needed the actual InvokeOperation not just the value since the InvokeOperation UserState can be valuable.  It should be noted that I haven't tested error handling at all.

```
public static class ObservableEx
{
      public static IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>> ObservableInvokeOperation<T, Tdat> (
         Func<Tdat, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> func,
         Tdat data,
         System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler scheduler )
      {
         return
             Observable.Defer<InvokeOperation<T>>( () =>
                 FromCallbackPattern<Tdat, T>( func, scheduler )
                     .Invoke( data ) );
      }

      private static Func<P, IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>>> FromCallbackPattern<P, T> (
          Func<P, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
          IScheduler scheduler )
      {
         return p =>
         {
            var subject = new AsyncSubject<InvokeOperation<T>>();
            try
            {
               call( p, iot =>
               {
                  if ( iot.HasError )
                  {
                     subject.OnError( iot.Error );
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     subject.OnNext( iot );
                     subject.OnCompleted();
                  }
               }, p );
            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
               subject.OnError( ex );
            }
            return subject.ObserveOn( scheduler );
         };
      }   
}
```

useage given function

```
public InvokeOperation<int> SomeFunc(SomeData data, Action<InvokeOperation<int>> callback, object userState)

var myobs = ObservableEx.ObservableInvokeOperation<int, SomeData>( myRIAContext.SomeFunc, data, Scheduler.ThreadPool );
```

This works great for any function that with matches the given function signature.  Unfortunately now I've run into some variations such as

```
Func<T1, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object>
Func<T1, T2, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object>
```

Anyone have any suggestions to convert this to be able to handle any InvokeOperation method I want to throw at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT1**: See below for a hybrid solution based on Paul Betts' answer and mine.

**EDIT2**: See below for a "third-generation" solution based on the OP's update.

---

The callback is a little difficult to deal with and I must say that turning this into an observable is a good way to go.

I've got an approach that worked for me.

The basic approach is to turn the `SomeFunc` operation into a `Func<T>` and then call `Observable.Start` on that. I've wrapped this in `Observable.Create` to keep it clean and I've added error handling. I've done basic testing, but nothing too robust.

Consuming the code looks like this:

```
var obs = service.SomeObservableFunc(new SomeData(), Scheduler.ThreadPool);
obs.Subscribe(t => { /* success */ }, ex => { /* error */ });
```

I've assumed that your RIA service class is `RiaService<T>` and built the `SomeObservableFunc` extension method like this:

```
    public static IObservable<T> SomeObservableFunc<T>(
        this RiaService<T> service,
        SomeData data,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
        {
            var error = (Exception)null;
            Func<T> call = () =>
            {
                var result = default(T);
                var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                Action<InvokeOperation<T>> callback = iot =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (iot.HasError)
                        {
                            error = iot.Error;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = iot.Value;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        error = ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        mre.Set();
                    }
                };
                try
                {
                    service.SomeFunc(data, callback, null);
                    mre.WaitOne();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    error = ex;
                }
                return result;
            };

            return Observable
                .Start(call, scheduler)
                .Subscribe(t =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (error == null)
                        {
                            o.OnNext(t);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            o.OnError(error);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        o.OnError(ex);
                    }
                }, ex => o.OnError(ex), () =>
                {
                    if (error == null)
                    {
                        o.OnCompleted();
                    }
                });
        });
    }
```

Yell out if this works for you.

---

### EDIT1

I liked Paul Betts' solution because it didn't use `ManualResetEvent`, but it didn't compile and also didn't handle internal errors that could occur during the RIA service call, so I've created the follow hybrid solution.

My extension method now looks like this:

```
    public static IObservable<T> SomeObservableFunc<T>(
        this RiaService<T> service,
        SomeData data,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return
            Observable.Defer<T>(() =>
                FromCallbackPattern<SomeData, T>(service.SomeFunc, scheduler)
                    .Invoke(data));
    }
```

And this uses the reworked `FromCallbackPattern` originally created by Paul Betts:

```
    private static Func<P, IObservable<T>> FromCallbackPattern<P, T>(
        Func<P, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return p =>
        {
            var subject = new AsyncSubject<T>();
            try
            {
                call(p, iot =>
                {
                    if (iot.HasError)
                    {
                        subject.OnError(iot.Error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        subject.OnNext(iot.Value);
                        subject.OnCompleted();
                    }
                }, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                subject.OnError(ex);
            }
            return subject.ObserveOn(scheduler);
        };
    }
```

It works against my test code and I think this is a nicer overall solution.

---

### EDIT2

This version of the solution is designed to allow differing number of parameters plus the user state to be passed to the `FromCallbackPattern` extension methods.

I started with this general purpose `FromCallbackPattern` extension method:

```
    public static IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>> FromCallbackPattern<T>(
        this Action<Action<InvokeOperation<T>>> call,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
        {
            var subject = new AsyncSubject<InvokeOperation<T>>();
            try
            {
                call(iot =>
                {
                    subject.OnNext(iot);
                    subject.OnCompleted();
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                subject.OnError(ex);
            }
            return subject.ObserveOn(scheduler);
        });
    }
```

Then I needed a series of private `Reduce` extension methods to reduce the various service calls down to `Action<Action<InvokeOperation<T>>>` delegates:

```
    private static Action<Action<InvokeOperation<T>>> Reduce<T>(
        this Func<Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        object state)
    {
        return a => call(a, state);
    }

    private static Action<Action<InvokeOperation<T>>> Reduce<P, T>(
        this Func<P, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        P p, object state)
    {
        return a => call(p, a, state);
    }       

    private static Action<Action<InvokeOperation<T>>> Reduce<P1, P2, T>(
        this Func<P1, P2, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        P1 p1, P2 p2, object state)
    {
        return a => call(p1, p2, a, state);
    }

    private static Action<Action<InvokeOperation<T>>> Reduce<P1, P2, P3, T>(
        this Func<P1, P2, P3, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, object state)
    {
        return a => call(p1, p2, p3, a, state);
    }

    private static Action<Action<InvokeOperation<T>>> Reduce<P1, P2, P3, P4, T>(
        this Func<P1, P2, P3, P4, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4, object state)
    {
        return a => call(p1, p2, p3, p4, a, state);
    }
```

Now I can write the plain `FromCallbackPattern` extension methods:

```
    public static Func<object, IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>>> FromCallbackPattern<T>(
        this Func<Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return o => call.Reduce(o).FromCallbackPattern(scheduler);
    }

    public static Func<P, object, IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>>> FromCallbackPattern<P, T>(
        this Func<P, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (p, o) => call.Reduce(p, o).FromCallbackPattern(scheduler);
    }

    public static Func<P1, P2, object, IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>>> FromCallbackPattern<P1, P2, T>(
        this Func<P1, P2, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (p1, p2, o) => call.Reduce(p1, p2, o).FromCallbackPattern(scheduler);
    }

    public static Func<P1, P2, P3, object, IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>>> FromCallbackPattern<P1, P2, P3, T>(
        this Func<P1, P2, P3, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (p1, p2, p3, o) => call.Reduce(p1, p2, p3, o).FromCallbackPattern(scheduler);
    }

    public static Func<P1, P2, P3, P4, object, IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>>> FromCallbackPattern<P1, P2, P3, P4, T>(
        this Func<P1, P2, P3, P4, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>> call,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (p1, p2, p3, p4, o) => call.Reduce(p1, p2, p3, p4, o).FromCallbackPattern(scheduler);
    }
```

And then, finally, the original `SomeObservableFunc`/`ObservableInvokeOperation` extension methods (now also renamed to `FromCallbackPattern`):

```
    public static IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>> FromCallbackPattern<T>(
        this RiaService<T> service,
        Func<RiaService<T>, Func<Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>>> call,
        object state,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
            call(service).FromCallbackPattern(scheduler)
                .Invoke(state));
    }

    public static IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>> FromCallbackPattern<P, T>(
        this RiaService<T> service,
        Func<RiaService<T>, Func<P, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>>> call,
        P p, object state,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
            call(service).FromCallbackPattern(scheduler)
                .Invoke(p, state));
    }

    public static IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>> FromCallbackPattern<P1, P2, T>(
        this RiaService<T> service,
        Func<RiaService<T>, Func<P1, P2, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>>> call,
        P1 p1, P2 p2, object state,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
            call(service).FromCallbackPattern(scheduler)
                .Invoke(p1, p2, state));
    }

    public static IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>> FromCallbackPattern<P1, P2, P3, T>(
        this RiaService<T> service,
        Func<RiaService<T>, Func<P1, P2, P3, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>>> call,
        P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, object state,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
            call(service).FromCallbackPattern(scheduler)
                .Invoke(p1, p2, p3, state));
    }   

    public static IObservable<InvokeOperation<T>> FromCallbackPattern<P1, P2, P3, P4, T>(
        this RiaService<T> service,
        Func<RiaService<T>, Func<P1, P2, P3, P4, Action<InvokeOperation<T>>, object, InvokeOperation<T>>> call,
        P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4, object state,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
            call(service).FromCallbackPattern(scheduler)
                .Invoke(p1, p2, p3, p4, state));
    }
```

Obviously you need to replace the references to `RiaService<T>` with your RIA service class type.

These methods can be called like this:

```
IObservable<InvokeOperation<int>> obs1 =
    service
        .FromCallbackPattern(
            s => s.SomeFunc,
            new SomeData(),
            null, // user state
            Scheduler.ThreadPool);

IObservable<InvokeOperation<int>> obs2 =
    service
        .FromCallbackPattern(
            s => s.SomeOtherFunc,
            42, "Hello", 3.14159265,
            null, // user state
            Scheduler.ThreadPool);
```

Phew! How's that now?

Comment: That seems to work for me.  I modified it to take a Func<> to make it reusable for all InvokeOperation methods.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this, please see my answer below - there's no reason you should be using Start or the ManualResetEvent

Comment: @PaulBetts - The reason I went with this approach is that `InvokeOperation<T>` catches its internal errors and exposes them via `HasError` & `Error` - I wrote the code to deal with that. Your code isn't catching these errors - I'll try a mod to make yours work and let you know.

Comment: @PaulBetts - I've created a hybrid solution which included a reworked version of your code. I hope you don't mind. I think we both had some issues with our original solutions and what I've put together works quite well I hope you agree.

Comment: I like this implementation better.  See my updated original post.  Thanks for your help all

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
public Func<T1, IObservable<TRet>> FromCallbackPattern<T1, TRet>(Action<T1, Action<TRet>, object> originalMethod)
{
    return new Func<T1, IObservable<TRet>>((param1) => {
        var subject = new AsyncSubject<TRet>();

        try {
            originalMethod(param1, (result) => {
                subject.OnNext(result);
                subject.OnCompleted();
            }, null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            subject.OnError(ex);
        }

        return subject;
    });
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var rxSomeFunc = FromCallbackPattern(someObj.SomeFunc);

rxSomeFunc(theData).Subscribe(x => ...);
```

Comment: I get the following errors: Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<T1,System.IObservable<TRet>>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.IObservable<TRet>'

Comment: @PaulBetts - You have one more issues in your code - the method signature should look like `Func<T1, IObservable<TRet>> FromCallbackPattern<T1, TRet>(Func<T1, Action<InvokeOperation<TRet>>, object, InvokeOperation<TRet>> originalMethod)`.